# Formatting a facebook date with PHP

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

How do I format facebook's date string using php into something a bit prettier?

the format returned by the facebook graph api is

```
2011-08-26T15:50:21+0000
```

but I would like to display it in the format

```
26 August at 15:50
```

how would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `strtotime` this will return a unix timestamp that you can then apply `date` on in your own format e.g..

```
$date = strtotime("2011-08-26T15:50:21+0000");
echo date("F j, Y, g:i a", $date);
```